# How do display products by category id in template page(.phtml page) in magento?

Tags: magento, categories, product

i am new to magento. i used below code in allproduct.phtml file for get all category id's.

```
function get_categories(){

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category'); 
$tree = $category->getTreeModel(); 
$tree->load();
$ids = $tree->getCollection()->getAllIds(); 
$arr = array();
if ($ids){ 
foreach ($ids as $id){ 
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category'); 
$cat->load($id);
$arr[$id] = $cat->getName();
} 
}

return $arr;

}
```

now i got category Id'd like below in one array,

```
Array
(
    [Root Catalog] => 1
    [Default Category] => 2
    [Multivitamins] => 3
    [Vitamins and Minerals] => 4
    [Joints and Arthritis] => 5
    [EFA's] => 6
    [Diet and Digestion] => 7
    [Mood, Mind and Specialty] => 8
    [cardiostrong™] => 9
    [Teas and Juices] => 10
    [Additional] => 11
)
```

Now i need to display all the products seperated by the above category id's.

How can i do this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the products in a category by calling `$category->getProductCollection()`.

Sample:

$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name');

foreach ($categories as $category) {
  $products = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name');
  echo sprintf("< h1>%d. %s", $category->getId(), $category->getName());
  foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo sprintf("%d. %s< br />",  $product->getId(), $product->getName());
  }
}

edit: I made the html tags wrong on purpose, to prevent them from being parsed.

Comment: thanks. i need product image url and link url also. How can i get that?. please advice me