# Magento: compiling a list of products from category

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system, categories

I am a bit of a noob at Magento, just started using it. So, what I'm trying to do is put together on a CMS page a simple list (a name - link pair) of all the products from a given category. To act as sort of an index. Inserting this block in my CMS page helped me move forward a bit.

> {{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list"
>   alias="products_homepage" category_id="9"
>   template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

However, this displays everything about a product (price, picture, add to cart button etc.), plus it only allows for max 30 entries per page.

I just need it to show a simple name - url pair. And if possible, without editing existing files. Any ideas or pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: There are a lot questions about this sort of things like this one from yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801391/how-do-display-products-by-category-id-in-template-page-phtml-page-in-magento/10802022#10802022. What is unique about your question?

Comment: The script from that link looks like it might work. In fact, I found a few suggestions that are similar to yours. But, where do I put this script? What's the best approach? Create a widget? I'm looking for a few more details on the answer. Figured StackOverflow is a good place to ask since the community here is quite knowledgeable of such things.

Comment: It is not so very easy and straightforward to explain. You should look around for tutorials about adding Blocks and design to magento, for example on magentocommerce.com

Comment: All right. I'll look around for blocks-related tutorials. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, got this working. The script looks kind of like this (the following only retrieves product names; obviously can be extended):

```
function getProdList ($catId)
{   
    $categories = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
    $categories->load($catId); // the id of your desired category
    $collection = $categories->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name');

    foreach ($collection as $product)
    {
        echo sprintf("%s<br />", $product->getName());
    }
}
```

When you invoke the function you just pass to it the ID of the category who's products you wish to view. Create a .phtml file, place it somewhere in your magento templates folder. Then you use a block statement in your CMS page where you want to insert the list:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="fileNameHere" template="path/to/file.phtml"}}
```

Thanks to Lucasmus for setting me on the right track. Hope this helps someone out there. Peace!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the informative post. For those of you who are not so fluent in PHP but landed on this page because you were looking for a solution to display a product name list from a given category I managed to find a solution by simply modifying someone else's template file.
For this solution I found the best suited extension was:
[freebie magento featured products-widget version-2](http://www.cubewebsites.com/blog/magento/extensions/freebie-magento-featured-products-widget-version-2/)
(find the latest version on github: [Cube-Category-Featured-Products](https://github.com/cubewebsites/Cube-Category-Featured-Products/tags)).

After logging in and out and clearing the cache I was able to insert the widget into a static block and modify the `.phtml` file used to produce the custom view that I wanted. The widget looked like this when inserted:

```
{{widget type="categoryfeatured/list" template="categoryfeatured/block.phtml" categories="118" num_products="10" products_per_row="1" product_type="all"}}.
```

I simply opened `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/categoryfeatured/block.phtml` copied it's contents and created a new `.phtml` file called `category_product_listing.phtml` and then pointed the widget instance to the new `.phtml` file as follows:

```
{{widget type="categoryfeatured/list" template="categoryfeatured/category_product_listing.phtml" categories="118" num_products="10" products_per_row="1" product_type="all"}}
```

I then went through this `.phtml` file with my basic understanding of PHP and removed all items like images, add to cart buttons, reviews, etc. until I was left with just the basic linked product title as well as the category title left intact.

I hope this helps someone as I spent hours trying to figure this out.